# Display Range Field Value on Change with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this range field and near it is the default value of 300 GBP.

```
<div class="filterField">
<label>Price:</label>
<input type="range" name="price" id="price" min="0" max="1000" value="300" />
<div class="rangeValue"><div id="valuePrice">300</div> GBP</div>
</div>
```

Now what I am trying to do is to change the value in `<div id="valuePrice"></div>` instantly when the users makes a change.

I've tried it with this script but it doesn't work:

```
$("#price").change(function () {                    
   var newValue = $('#price').val();
   $("#valuePrice").replaceWith(newValue);
});
```

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("#valuePrice").html(newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

change event is fired when the textbox is blur. You can use keyup event if you want the div to be updated instantly when user typing:

```
$("#price").keyup(function () {                    
   var newValue = $('#price').val();
   $("#valuePrice").html(newValue);
});
```